# Rxjs map method return undefined

Tags: rxjs

I'm tring to learn rxjs but i'm having some problems with the map operator. Here's my code:

```
    const courses$ = http$.pipe(map(res => {res['payload']}))

    courses$.subscribe(
        (datas) => {console.log(datas)},
        noop,
        () => {console.log('finished')}
      )
```

`createObservable()` is a function that i defined. It simply makes an http request to a db and return the datas in json format. I tested it out and works.
Debbuging I saw that console logging `res['payload']`  directly in map works, but when i console log it in the observable subscribe return undefined. Here there is a picture of the structure of the dats that i recive from the db[image]. Thank u all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're not actually returning in your `map`, change to:

```
const courses$ = http$.pipe(map(res => res['payload']))
```

adding `{}` around the function requires a `return` statement

Comment: glad it did. feel free to mark it